# what should be the argument in facebook authentication function in laravel?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, laravel-5

I have a function for Facebook authentication.

```
public function loginWithFacebook(Request $request){

        // get data from request
        $code = $request->get('code');
        // get fb service
        $fb = \OAuth::consumer('Facebook');

        // check if code is valid

        // if code is provided get user data and sign in
        if ( ! is_null($code))
        {
            // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
            $token = $fb->requestAccessToken($code);
            // Send a request with it

            $result = json_decode($fb->request('/me?fields=name,email,gender,age_range'), true);
            print_r($result1);

        }
        // if not ask for permission first
        else
        {

            // get fb authorization
            $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();
            // return to facebook login url
            return redirect((string)$url);

        }

    }
```

I want to call this function from another controller.
So I do this:

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\socialMedia')->loginWithFacebook(Request $request);
```

but it returns the error 
**syntax error, unexpected '$request' (T_VARIABLE)**

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public function loginWithFacebook(Request $request){
> ```

This is called type hinting. The method is declared in a way that it will only accept a first parameter that is an instance of `Request`.

> ```
> app('App\Http\Controllers\socialMedia')->loginWithFacebook(Request $request);
> ```

That is a method *call*, and in those you just pass the parameter – to specify a type at this point makes no sense.

So the correct way to call the method should be

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\socialMedia')->loginWithFacebook($request);
```